# I've Featured some Paragraph Bundles, but they are not showing up on the remote site

Tags: 7, features, paragraphs

I've Featured some Paragraph bundles and have included them as part of a module.

I've merged these files to my remote site and want to 'activate' the Feature to have the Paragraph Bundles appear. I see my Feature there on the remote site and can 'Revert' it to update it but nothing happens - I don't get my new Paragraph Bundles in the existing list, nor do I get any error messages.

Would anyone know what's going on?

What I've pushed up is:

```
module_name.features.field_instance.inc

function module_name_field_default_field_instances() {
  $field_instances = array();

  // Exported field_instance:
  // 'paragraphs_item-module_name-field_grid_number_columns'.
  $field_instances['paragraphs_item-module_name-field_grid_number_columns'] = array( etc...
```

And

```
module_name.features.inc

function 
module_name_paragraphs_info() {
  $items = array( etc...
```

And in my module's .info file I have included, eg:

```
features[features_api][] = api:2
features[field_instance][] = paragraphs_item-module_name-field_grid_number_columns
features[field_instance][] = paragraphs_item-module_name-field_paragraphs
features[field_instance][] = paragraphs_item-module_name_item-field_image
features[field_instance][] = paragraphs_item-module_name_item-field_text
features[field_instance][] = paragraphs_item-module_name_item-field_title
features[paragraphs][] = module_name
features[paragraphs][] = module_name_item
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You might try manually creating the paragraph bundle and see if the fields pop in once the bundle is made, or once the bundle is made and the feature is reverted.

Might be that the features integration for paragraphs in D7 is still iffy.